# click event in list view is ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a class extended with android.app.ListFragment and I want to make an event when the list view is clicked ,but nothing is working for me and am using array adapter.
I have tried almost everything and now am trying this but still its not working.

```
ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
          Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
       } 
    });
```

My adapter fragment class is:

Comment: what exactly is not working? did you try debugging your code? did you try debug logs?

Comment: done everything check my edited question with adapter fragment class.

Comment: @flx just click on the list view is not working.

Comment: try 
rootView.setFocusable(false);
rootView.setClickable(false);

Comment: or any other view that might have consumed the onClick event

Comment: tried but still no result.

Comment: how about override the onListItemClick method in your class that extends ListFragment?

Comment: I mean override onListItemClick method for your Listfragment class.
So remove all things getListView().setOnItemClickListener......
and then override onListItemClick method after your onCreateView method.

Comment: @WilliamLAM have already tried this but getListView() gives an error/

Comment: not using getListView() at all. See my another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaasdasdaccant",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: thank you man , you really are the life saver !!!! I too much banged my head with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

reference:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `onListItemClick` method of `ListFragment`.

So delete

```
ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
   } 
});
```

and add to your class

```
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do what you need
}
```